# Apply css class in component that will effect entire css angular 6

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have one component

**my.component.ts**
That has its own css like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**my.component.css**

```
.hello{
color:red;
}
```

The problem is that i want to use that class to be visible in entire project in html, i know i can put them globally, but i want to use it from component.

Now other components does not see that class :(

Is there some kind of solution in Angular?

Comment: Any specific reason you don't want to put it in global css file? as you want to access it throughout the project

Comment: Because that component and all modules and services i want to use them in another project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the documentation on [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation), especially at the "None" part:

> None means that Angular does no view encapsulation. Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. The scoping rules, isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the HTML.

Apply it to the component decorators config object:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // <-- This
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your css to `app.component.css` or `style.css`. It will effect on whole application.

Comment: OP already mentioned the fact he knows the fact he can put them globally but he don't want to do so

Comment: He want to use from component.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your component css style to be accessible from other component the solution is [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation).

Example :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Angular comes with view encapsulation built in, which enables us to use Shadow DOM or even emulate it, so what **ViewEncapsulation.None** will do is remove the shadow DOM, so there will be no style encapsulation